# how to automatically move box to bottom when resize?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
<div class="main">
<div class="cleft">
</div>
<div class="cright">
</div>
</div>

.cleft{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
    width: 68%;
}

.cright{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 1%;
    width: 28%;
}
```

I have two box left and right. I want a thing that I want to put left and right box width:100% when someone resize the width and width are less then the main-container (1075px in my case).

How I can make 100% width of left and right and right will shown on bottom.

note: I have made some changes for ipad,iphone and they work fine in that case. but How I can applied for that thing when someone resize the browser.

Comment: Please someone edit it for better understanding.

Comment: Do someone have any trick to write css against all device have less size then needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use media queries:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1075px) {
   .cleft, .cright {
       float:none;
       width:50%;
       padding:none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. this is really what I want. only a modification that width is 100% for taking full width of screen.